# Wicket info, warn, error messages

Tags: java, wicket

I need to implement some kind of a component that will trigger some functions depending on message type (WARNING, ERROR, INFO), so feedback panel is not suitable for this purpose. I don't know how to fetch these messages on every request, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the source code for FeedbackPanel and see what that component does. There are some APis available to get at the messages. With some browsing you can see that FeedbackPanel ultimately uses [FeedbackCollector](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-6.x/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/feedback/FeedbackCollector.java) to collect the available messages. Either you can use the FeedbackCollector directly, or use it as an example for your own code.